# generate entities (JPA) in IBM RAD

Tags: java, jpa, entities, ibm-rad

I was trying to generate entities from tables using IBM RAD 8.5. I see couple of tables generate with columns properly but couple of tables without any column names.

After that I have generated entity one after the other (I have tried two of that kind) but when I try generating all at once again it fails. DB (Oracle) end every thing is fine.

There is no error to post here, please help me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: experts please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/create-jpa-entities-rational-application-developer-1/ It's probably form some older version of RAD, but it worked for me. You should provide more detailed information about your problem in order to get some help.

Comment: Using links as answers is not a good fit for stackoverflow - it is better to insert a quote from the target link that can help readers...